# How is the tax rate calculated?

Tags: heroes-of-hammerwatch

In Heroes of Hammerwatch, whenever you send gold and ore to the town you have to pay a certain tax on the gold, i.e. a percentage of the gold you collected is lost.

How is this tax rate calculated?

- I noticed, the tax rate increases the more money I have in the town.
- The treasury building reduces tax rate, but by how much?
- Does the level of the dungeon I'm in influence tax rate?
- Does the ore I carry have any bearing on the tax rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tax rate is based off of your total gold (in town and in the dungeon). I've noticed that 5000 gold in town but 0 in the dungeon will have a higher tax rate than if you had 0 gold in the town but 5000 gold in the dungeon. Don't know exactly why this is but it's currently like that.

The base tax rate is 50% for 10,000 gold without any Treasury upgrades. As you upgrade the treasury, your threshold increases. So if you have max Treasury upgrades, the tax rate will be 50% at 25,000 gold. Therefore, at 12,500 gold you should be taxed 25%.

The level of the dungeon doesn't affect tax rate. I've read others attest to this as well.

The ore does not have any bearing on tax rate. Therefore, if you don't have anything you want to spend your money on but don't want to be taxed super heavily then you might want to consider buying ore (the buy/sell rate isn't optimal but it is better than being taxed 40-50% from the get go).

Comment: That's a good answer. Do you also know what the maximum tax rate is?

Comment: The highest tax rate I've observed is when I had 116,000 gold in the town and it had a tax rate of 82.40%. I've read someone who apparently had 97% tax rate after hundreds of thousands of gold. 

Highest tax rate in the dungeon I've seen without any gold in town (and with max treasury levels) is 68% with 331,000 gold in the dungeon.

Comment: _"Therefore, at 12,500 gold you should be taxed 25%"_ - are you sure?  The rate clearly does not increase linearly (based on the above comment), so that seems unlikely.