# Do you pay a gold tax when beating the final boss?

Tags: heroes-of-hammerwatch

Throughout the game, you can deposit your found gold and ore in elevators to take to the surface, at a tax rate that depends on how much gold you have collected. I decided to be brave, and do an entire run from start to finish without depositing once.

I entered the final boss' arena with this collection:

[image]

But upon beating it and returning to town, I was met with this amount of gold:

[image]

Note that i had 50 Ore in my inventory prior to this run.

Are you taxed after beating the final boss and returning to town? Does the final boss have some attack that drains your money? I feel a bit cheated, to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you kill the final boss or not, you will get taxed. The simple fact of getting money back from the dungeon to the city leads to taxes.

According to the [game's wiki](http://wiki.heroesofhammerwatch.com/Money):

> The town of Hammerwatch taxes all players for its services, **taking a part of all the gold players send back to town**.

> Defeating the final boss will double the tax midpoint, **then send all carried gold and ore to town**.

You can use the [following tool](https://themadsword.github.io/hoh-taxcalc.html) to calculate how much gold you will bring back with you if you do a full run.

About how the tax system works, I advise reading [this other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327921/how-is-the-tax-rate-calculated).

Comment: What does it mean by "double the tax midpoint"?

Comment: @nightsurfer At the start of the game, players have a 50% tax rate at 10K gold, which is the tax midpoint. The more you progress in the game, the more you can increase this threshold (initially 10K), for instance by buying Treasury upgrades, getting the Papers of Nobility item, or getting the Offshore Account fortune from the fountain. Beating the final boss is also one of these, multiplying this value by two.

Comment: Ah okay so it's not doubling the tax %, it's doubling the gold amount before the max tax rate. I think I get it, thanks!